# pip install psycopg2 - error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, psycopg2, python-wheel

I get the following error when trying to install `psycopg2`:

```
   (venv) root@scw-determined-panini:/app# pip install psycopg2
    Collecting psycopg2
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/8f/1c5690eebf148d1d1554fc00ccf9101e134636553dbb75bdfef4f85d7647/psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... error
      Complete output from command /app/venv/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-psll6xe_/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp52or8xexpip-wheel- --python-tag cp38:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:0:
      ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       #include <libpq-fe.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      
      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
      
      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      
      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for psycopg2
      Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
    Failed to build psycopg2
    Installing collected packages: psycopg2
      Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
        Complete output from command /app/venv/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-psll6xe_/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x62dcj9d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        running build_ext
        building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
        In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:0:
        ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
         #include <libpq-fe.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        
        It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
        
        You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
        If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
        required for the build and try again.
        
        For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
        <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
        
        error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
        
        ----------------------------------------
    Command "/app/venv/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-psll6xe_/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x62dcj9d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-psll6xe_/psycopg2/
    (venv) root@scw-determined-panini:/app# psycopg2-binary
    psycopg2-binary: command not found
    (venv) root@scw-determined-panini:/app# pip install psycopg2-binary
    Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+libpq-fe.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For Ubuntu use

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

thanks

Comment: Its works for me. I have Ubuntu 20.04, python 3.7. Thank a lot

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you install postgresql before installing psycopg2 ?

Comment: Thank you, also solved the problem for me on ubuntu 20.10 and python 3.8.10

Comment: @codingbruh In my case, it was AFTER installing Postgres v14. This command solved the problem.

Comment: Worked for me also,  Ubuntu desktop 21.04 and after installing PostgreSQL v14.2  before psycopg2.